# How to implement a nested CrossValidator in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, scikit-learn

I am trying to scale to large datasets and pandas is running out of memory. I am trying to move to pyspark.

I am using a nested kfold for cross validation. I struggle to find any way to have nested kfolds/crossvalidators using strictly pyspark.

How do you create nested CrossValidators in PySpark?

```
sample_splitting = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

# Configure prediction models and set of hyper-parameters
rf = RandomForestRegressor(random_state=42)
param_grid = {
    'max_depth': [5, 10],
    'min_samples_leaf': [500],
    'n_estimators': [500],
    'max_features': ['onethird', 'sqrt']
}

predictions = list()

for train_ix, test_ix in sample_splitting.split(X):
    X_train, X_test = X.iloc[train_ix], X.iloc[test_ix]
    y_train, y_test = y.iloc[train_ix], y.iloc[test_ix]

    cv_tune = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=42)

    rfcv = GridSearchCV(rf, param_grid, cv=cv_tune, n_jobs=-1, refit=True)

    rfcv.fit(X_train, y_train)
    residual.append(y_test - rfcv.predict(X_test))

df[prediction] = pd.concat(residual, axis=0)
```